# what is diffrence between @Endpoint and @WebService?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am little bit confused about these two annotations.I want to implement spring web services.
Please help me to add some knowledge regarding these two concepts.
thank you.

Comment: @endpoint is a way of spring to define a web service which is specific to spring only whereas @ webservice is a standard of jax-ws API

Comment: Can we use @ webservice  in spring?

Comment: yes you can use its java standard

Comment: Yes i have tried but not have satisfactory explanations.

Comment: Gave it a go, just by searching "java web service endpoint annotation" gives plenty of good explanations and details.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-services-jax-ws-vs-spring

Comment: @Vallentin check out [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) before instructing people here to go for google.

Comment: Addition to @raffian's comment. This tutorial might also be useful: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/

Answer (score 2):

@ webservice  ıs for java-ws standard ,already you can use it in spring,but spring data  has his own webservice that use @endpoint annotation